# turning off Redefined static procedure in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

anyone of you could tell me how to turn off "Redefined static procedure" warnings? 
I red online documentation of swi-prolog and i found this predicate

```
 no_style_check(ultimate)
```

that in principle should turn off these warnings, but when i execute this predicate

```
main:-  
  no_style_check(singleton),
  no_style_check(discontiguous),
  no_style_check(multiple),
  require,
  test_all.
```

i received this error

> ERROR: Domain error: `style_name' expected, found`multiple'

Anyone knows an alternative way to do this or could tell me why i receive this error ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better to mark the procedures you intend to redefine all over the place with `:- dynamic my_proc/1.` and `:- discontiguous my_proc/1.` than to disable this functionality, which can be a great help in debugging. I would **strongly** encourage you not to turn off singleton "warnings" because they are almost always in practice evidence of faulty coding.

Comment: Thanks for help! But i haven't understood the syntax of these predicates. Could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 3):

Prolog is a pretty loosey-goosey language, so by default it warns you when you do certain things that are not *wrong* per se, but tend to be a good indication that you've made a typo.

Now, suppose you write something like this:

```
myfoo(3, 3).
myfoo(N, M) :- M is N*4+1.
```

Then from the prompt you write this:

```
?- asserta(myfoo(7,9)).
ERROR: asserta/1: No permission to modify static procedure `myfoo/2'
ERROR: Defined at user://1:9
```

What's happening here is that you haven't told Prolog that it's OK for you to modify `myfoo/2` so it is stopping you. The trick is to add a declaration:

```
:- dynamic myfoo/2.
myfoo(3, 3).
myfoo(N, M) :- M is N*4+1.
```

Now it will let you modify it just fine:

```
?- asserta(myfoo(7,9)).
true.
```

Now suppose you have three modules and they each advertise themselves by defining some predicate. For instance, you might have three files.

**foo.pl**

```
can_haz(foo).
```

**bar.pl**

```
can_haz(bar).
```

When you load them both you're going to get a warning:

```
?- [foo].
true.

?- [bar].
Warning: /home/fox/HOME/Projects/bar.pl:1:
        Redefined static procedure can_haz/1
        Previously defined at /home/fox/HOME/Projects/foo.pl:1
true.
```

And notice this:

```
?- can_haz(X).
X = bar.
```

The `foo` solution is gone.

The trick here is to tell Prolog that clauses of this predicate may be defined in different files. The trick is `multifile`:

**foo.pl**

```
:- multifile can_haz/1.
can_haz(foo).
```

**bar.pl**

```
:- multifile can_haz/1.
can_haz(bar).
```

In use:

```
?- [foo].
true.

?- [bar].
true.

?- can_haz(X).
X = foo ;
X = bar.
```

`:- discontiguous` does the same thing as multifile except in a single file; so you define clauses of the same predicate in different places in one file.

Again, singleton warnings are a completely different beast and I would absolutely not modify the warnings on them, they're too useful in debugging.

Comment: thanks so much for help! It's works perfectly. The last questions is why swipl doesn't accepts the term "multifile" in `no_style_check()` predicate?
Nevertheless i red that predicate accepts `[all,single_var,discontiguous,multifile]`.

Comment: SWIPL seems to have [style_check/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=style_check/1) instead, and it doesn't accept multifile. Are you looking at some other system's documentation? This is not an ISO feature, BTW.